# Galaxy S3 Accounts & Sync gone after jellybean update 4.1.1

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Just updated my new Galaxy S3 to latest jellybean update 4.1.1 and my accounts and sync disappeared. Tech support said it should be under settings / personal tab but not there. 
Any ideas of what happened?

Answer (score 1):

On my Galaxy S3 wich I updated about two weeks ago, there is an "Accounts" part in the settings, right after the "Personal" one, where all my accounts are listed. Do you have it ?
I can also access to the sync settings from the contacts list, then press the menu touch button (on the left of the home button) and choose accounts.